# wp_dropdown_categories not changing value_field to slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp_dropdown_categories() function for displaying category dropdown. I am passing following array argument to show taxonomy slug in option value.

```
'value_field'      => 'slug',
```

But I am facing problem related to option values. It is showing taxonomy id instead of slug.

```
$category_args = array(
   'show_option_none' => 'Category',
   'hide_empty'       => 0,
   'hierarchical'     => TRUE,
   'name'             => 'selected_category',
   'taxonomy'         => 'taxonomy_name',
   'value_field'      => 'slug',
);

                    // Display or retrieve the HTML dropdown list of job category
wp_dropdown_categories( $category_args );
```

Any idea about this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this code ,i have check it and it is working

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Select category' ),
        'show_count'       => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'echo'             => 0,
         'value_field'      => 'slug',
    );
    ?>

    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

    <?php echo $select; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <?php
$category_args = array(
                        'show_option_none' => 'Category',
                       'value_field'      => 'slug',
                        'hide_empty'       => 0,
                       'hierarchical'     => TRUE,

                    );

                    // Display or retrieve the HTML dropdown list of job category
wp_dropdown_categories( $category_args ); ?>
```

I hope this code will work for you.